# Insert from code or store procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, performance, insert

Well i have to do a series of updates and inserts.

I have this code on vb.net

```
Dim posicion_id As Integer = MysqlObj.ejecutarInsert("INSERT INTO posicion (dispositivoid, mensajeid, fechahora, longitud, latitud, altura, velocidad, direccion, resultadoid, descripcion, gpsweek, gpsseconds, notificacionenviada, positiontype) VALUES (" + msj.dispositivoid + "," + msj.mensajeid + ",'" + msj.fechahora + "','" + msj.longitud + "','" + msj.latitud + "'," + msj.altura + "," + msj.velocidad + "," + msj.direccion + "," + msj.resultadoid + ",'" + msj.descripcion + "'," + msj.gpsweek + "," + msj.gpsseconds + "," + msj.notificacionenviada + "," + msj.positiontype + "); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").ToString()
        If (Integer.Parse(msj.mensajeid) > 0) Then
            MysqlObj.ejecutarInsert("INSERT INTO mensajedescripcion (mensajeid, fechahora, dispositivoid, secuencia) VALUES (" + msj.mensajeid + ",'" + msj.fechahora + "'," + msj.dispositivoid + ",0)")
        End If
        MysqlObj.ejecutarUpdate("UPDATE dispositivo SET ultimoMensaje = '" + msj.fechahora + "', fechanotificacion = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE dispositivoid = " + msj.dispositivoid)
        If (MysqlObj.hasRows("SELECT * FROM posicion_current WHERE dispositivoid = " + msj.dispositivoid)) Then
            MysqlObj.ejecutarUpdate("UPDATE posicion_current SET posicionid = " + posicion_id.ToString() + ", mensajeid = " + msj.mensajeid + ", fechahora = '" + msj.fechahora + "', longitud = '" +
                                    msj.longitud + "', latitud = '" + msj.latitud + "', altura = " + msj.altura + ", velocidad = " + msj.velocidad + ", direccion = " + msj.direccion + ", resultadoid = " + msj.resultadoid + ", descripcion = '" + msj.descripcion +
                                    "', gpsweek = " + msj.gpsweek + ", gpsseconds = " + msj.gpsseconds + ", notificacionenviada = " + msj.notificacionenviada + " WHERE dispositivoid = " + msj.dispositivoid)
        Else
            MysqlObj.ejecutarInsert("INSERT INTO posicion_current (posicionid, mensajeid, fechahora, longitud, latitud, altura, velocidad, direccion, resultadoid, descripcion, gpsweek, gpsseconds, notificacionenviada) VALUES (" + posicion_id + "," + msj.mensajeid + ",'" + msj.fechahora + "','" + msj.longitud + "','" + msj.latitud +
"'," + msj.altura + "," + msj.velocidad + "," + msj.direccion + "," + msj.resultadoid + ",'" + msj.descripcion + "'," + msj.gpsweek + "," + msj.gpsseconds + "," + msj.notificacionenviada + ")")
```

Is it better for performance to do it like that or a single stored procedure that receives all data and does each insert update

```
        DECLARE existss INT DEFAULT 0;
INSERT INTO posicion (dispositivoid, mensajeid, fechahora, longitud, latitud, altura, velocidad, direccion, resultadoid, descripcion, gpsweek, gpsseconds, notificacionenviada, positiontype)
 VALUES (_dipositivoid, _mensajeid, _fechahora, _longitud, _latitud, _altura, _velocidad, _direccion, 0, _descripcion, 0, 0, 1, 4219724); 
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @existss FROM posicion_current WHERE dispositivoid = _dispositivoid
 IF (@existss > 0) THEN
    UPDATE posicion_current SET posicionid = LAST_INSERT_ID(), mensajeid = _mensajeid, fechahora = _fechahora, longitud = _longitud, latitud = _latitud, 
    altura = _altura, velocidad = _velocidad, direccion = _direccion, resultadoid = 0, descripcion = _descripcion, gpsweek = 0, gpsseconds = 0, notificacionenviada = 1
    WHERE dispositivoid = _dispositivoid;
     ELSE
    INSERT INTO posicion_current (dispositivoid, mensajeid, fechahora, longitud, latitud, altura, velocidad, direccion, resultadoid, descripcion, gpsweek, gpsseconds, notificacionenviada)
    VALUES (_dipositivoid, _mensajeid, _fechahora, _longitud, _latitud, _altura, _velocidad, _direccion, 0, _descripcion, 0, 0, 1); 
 END IF;
 UPDATE dispositivo SET ultimoMensaje = _fechahora, fechanotificacion = NOW() WHERE dispositivoid = _dispositivoid;
 INSERT INTO mensajedescripcion (mensajeid, fechahora, dispositivoid, secuencia) VALUES (_mensajeid, _fechahora, _dispositivoid, 0);
```

Comment: I think that your main concern should be how to start using parameterized queries.

Comment: lol is just for example, im just trying to figure out if there is a difference in performance

Comment: You have the two approaches, use `DateTime` before and after the code in VB.net, then `Subtract()`.  And let us know what you find.

Comment: I see no real distinctions but I didn't think of that approach so thank you rick

Answer (score 0):

Change the COUNT(*)...IF...UPDATE...ELSE...INSERT into

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

That will be faster and simpler.